Folders empty when mounted with sshfs, "reply len too large", reading directory '/': I/O error, works fine with other clients like Filezilla
I use a custom Alpine Linux 3.20.0 Docker container.
When mounting a remote sftp directory:
sshfs -v -o debug -p $backup_port test@$backup_server:/ /mnt/sftp/
and trying to read folders I get the following error:
/mnt/sftp # ls backup/
ls: reading directory 'backup/': I/O error

Server version: 3
Extension: statvfs@openssh.com <2>
[00001] LSTAT
  [00001]          ATTRS       41bytes (1ms)
[00002] LSTAT
  [00002]         STATUS       33bytes (1ms)
[00003] OPENDIR
  [00003]         HANDLE       14bytes (0ms)
[00004] READDIR
[00005] READDIR
  [00004]           NAME      296bytes (0ms)
  [00005]         STATUS       24bytes (0ms)
[00006] READDIR
[00007] READDIR
[00008] CLOSE
  [00006]         STATUS       24bytes (0ms)
  [00007]         STATUS       24bytes (0ms)
[00009] LSTAT
  [00008]         STATUS       21bytes (0ms)
  [00009]         STATUS       33bytes (0ms)
[00010] LSTAT
  [00010]         STATUS       33bytes (0ms)
[00011] OPENDIR
  [00011]         HANDLE       14bytes (0ms)
[00012] READDIR
[00013] READDIR
**reply len too large: 211607**

sent:               13 messages, 219 bytes
received:           11 messages, 557 bytes
rtt min/max/avg:    0ms/1ms/0ms
num connect:        1

It seems like the reply length is too large, is there anything I can do about it?
The folder contains about 160.000 files with a total size of about 3TB. It worked fine until the folder seemingly got to big.
When mounting the same folder in Filezilla, I get no errors at all and am able to read, create, move delete files etc.
I rebuilt my container with the newest Alpine version.
